# Create a geoJson object in C#

Tags: c#, geojson

am trying to create a GeoJson FeatureCollection object by passing ONLY lat and long to a function where it instantiate Below PoCo.

```
namespace PoCo
{

public class LocalGeometry
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class LocalFeature
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public LocalGeometry geometry { get; set; }
    public Properties properties { get; set; }
}

public class geoJson
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public List<LocalFeature> features { get; set; }
}

}
```

This is how am creating object

```
var CorOrd = new LocalGeometry();
            CorOrd.coordinates.Add(Lat);
            CorOrd.coordinates.Add(Lang);
            CorOrd.type = "Point";


var geoJson = new geoJson
            {
                type = "FeatureCollection",
                features = new LocalFeature
                {
                    type = "Feature",
                    geometry = CorOrd
                }
            };
```

But Am Getting Error

`CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'PoCo' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<PoCo.Local>'.`

Any Suggestions how do i create a GeoJson Object here.

Comment: @Win Thank you its a Big Win !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following assignment is not valid -

`features = new LocalFeature`

It should be a ***List of LocalFeature*** -

```
features = new List<LocalFeature>
{
   new LocalFeature { type = "Feature", geometry = CorOrd}
}
```

In addition, you will need to instantiate a list before adding. Otherwise, it will throw **NullReferenceException**.

```
ar CorOrd = new LocalGeometry();
CorOrd.coordinates = new List<double>(); // <=====
CorOrd.coordinates.Add(Lat);
CorOrd.coordinates.Add(Lang);
CorOrd.type = "Point";
```

Comment: You an also use property initializers to initialize it with `new LocalGeometry { coordinates = new List<double> { Lat, Long }, type = "Point" }`